# How can I read the contents from a file whose name I receive in the command line in ASM

Tags: assembly, tasm

I want to read the name of a file from the command line. The name is stored in var4, then I read from the file whose name I received  and store the text inside it in var2. Then I want to display the contents from the file. When I give the name directly, without using the command line (storing the name in var1, and then opening the file with that name) it works correctly. But when I use the name I received in the command line, even though they have the same name, it doesnt work. How can I fix this. 
I am using TASM

```
datos segment
var3 db 128 dup(0)
var2 db 128 dup(0)
handle dw 0
var1 db "c:\xxx.txt",0
var4 db 10 dup(0)

datos ends

pila segment stack "stack"
dw 256 dup(?)
pila ends


codigo segment
assume cs:codigo, ds:datos, ss:pila

inicio:
     mov ax,ds
     mov es,ax

     mov ax, datos
     mov ds,ax

     mov ax,pila
     mov ss,ax



     mov si, 80h
     mov cl, byte ptr es:[si]
     xor ch, ch

     xor di, di
     inc si
ciclo: inc si
      mov al, byte ptr es:[si]
      mov byte ptr var4[di], al
      inc di

      loop ciclo
      mov byte ptr var4[di],0


      mov ah,3dh
      lea dx,var4
      mov al,00h
      int 21h
      mov word ptr handle ,ax

      inc di
      mov byte ptr var4[di],0dh
      inc di
      mov byte ptr var4[di],0ah

      mov ah,3fh
      mov bx, handle
      mov cx,100h
      lea dx,var2
      int 21h 

      xor si,si
      xor di,di
      mov cl,ds:[si]

    ciclo2: 
      mov al, byte ptr var2[si]

      mov byte ptr var3[di], al
     inc si
     inc di
    loop ciclo2
      mov byte ptr var3[di],'$'


     mov ah,09h
     lea dx,var3
     int 21h

     fin:
     mov ax,4C00H
     int 21h
 codigo ends

 end inicio
```

Comment: Your code needs comments to explain the different blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov si, 80h
>  mov cl, byte ptr es:[si]
>  xor ch, ch
>  xor di, di
>  inc si                       <<< Remove this instruction!
> ciclo: inc si
>  mov al, byte ptr es:[si]
>  mov byte ptr var4[di], al
>  inc di
>  loop ciclo
>  mov byte ptr var4[di],0
> ```

The code that extracts the filespecification is wrong. Working with the byte count from the first byte of the command line is fine, but since you're using pre-incrementation on the index in SI you should not skip the byte count with a separate instruction. With your current code you've ignored an important first character and included the terminating carriage return in the filespec. Both give a failure on opening the file.

---

> ```
> var1 db "c:\xxx.txt",0
> var4 db 10 dup(0)
> ```

If at the command line you wrote "c:\xxx.txt" then you would better enlarge the buffer at *var4* because 10 bytes is too few. You add a null-byte, you add a carriage return, and you add a newline. By the way: what's  the use of adding **CRLF after a null-byte**? It would make sense though at the end of the *ciclo2* loop and before adding the $-sign.

---

> ```
> var2 db 128 dup(0)
> ...
> mov ah,3fh
> mov bx, handle
> mov cx,100h
> lea dx,var2
> int 21h
> ```

You're reading more than the buffer at *var2* can hold!

---

> ```
> xor si,si
> xor di,di
> mov cl,ds:[si]
> ```

What do you expect at address zero in DS ?
Why not initialize CH at zero? (`loop` requires the whole CX)

---

> ```
> ciclo2: 
> mov al, byte ptr var2[si]
> mov byte ptr var3[di], al
> inc si
> inc di
> loop ciclo2
> ```

Because of the use of `mov cx,100h` previously and only setting the CL register this loop will execute too many times!

Comment: I would rather advice to **not** remove the extra `inc si` but add an extra `dec cx` directly below it! This will quickly remove the *almost inevitable* space character that every commandline starts with.

Comment: @SepRoland I was more thinking along the lines of weeding out the leading whitespace because a DOS command line can legally start with a switchchar or __any number of spaces and tabs__. If the OP wants a quick fix then of course your suggestion is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some theory first (as Peter Cordes likes) : the PSP (program segment prefix) is a data structure stored in memory that holds info about the current program. Starting at offset 80h of the PSP we found the DTA, where the program arguments are. The first byte of the DTA is its length (length of arguments string).

In order to get the arguments it's possible to access the PSP, then jump to offset 80h, like this :

```
mov ah, 62h   ;SERVICE TO GET PSP SEGMENT.
int 21h       ;PSP SEGMENT RETURNS IN BX.
mov es, bx    ;ES POINTS TO PSP SEGMENT.
mov si, 80h   ;NOW ES:SI POINTS TO DTA.
```

But there is another service to get the DTA directly (https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=XxP8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=int+21h+ah%3D2fh&source=bl&ots=130J9jR69I&sig=vu3vqrIpvtcvqxE-3KOwTwb2LZk&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=int%2021h%20ah%3D2fh&f=false) :

```
mov ah, 2fh   ;SERVICE TO GET DTA ADDRESS.
int 21h       ;RETURNS ES:BX POINTING TO DTA.
```

To get the program arguments, we need to remember that, from command-line, arguments finish with ENTER key (char 13), so, starting at offset 1 of the DTA, we read chars until 13 is found. It's also possible to use the first byte (the length), but this will include the char 13 as part of the filename, and we don't want that.

Now the changes to the program, pointed by arrows ("<======") :

```
inicio:
     mov ax,ds
     mov es,ax

     mov ax, datos
     mov ds,ax

     mov ax,pila
     mov ss,ax

     mov si, 80h
;     mov cl, byte ptr es:[si]     ;<========== UNNECESSARY BECAUSE WE ARE
;     xor ch, ch                   ;<========== NOT USING THE LENGTH BYTE.

     xor di, di
     inc si
ciclo: inc si
      mov al, byte ptr es:[si]
      CMP AL, 13                   ;<========== IF THIS IS CHAR 13...
      JE  CICLO_FIN                ;<========== ... FINISH BLOCK.
      mov byte ptr var4[di], al
      inc di
      JMP CICLO                    ;<========== REPEAT.
;      loop ciclo                  ;<========== UNNECESSARY.
ciclo_fin:                         ;<=============================
      mov byte ptr var4[di],0
```

Comment: The PSP segment is in DS and ES at the start so there's no need ask MS-DOS where it is. Other than the redundant copying of DS to ES, that's the not the problem with the code.

Comment: @RossRidge, fixed!

Comment: Why scan for `\r` instead of using the length?  Can it be different?  Do you still get a trailing `\r` on your command line args if your program is run from a batch file?  (I knew DOS command-line args suck compared to Unix (where the shell parses them for you) but I find it hilarious that a carriage-return is part of the args.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I tested it, the 13 is at the end of the arguments (not hilarius, it's real), that's what made me answer this question.

Comment: I wasn't saying you're wrong, I'm saying I'm glad I never had to write code for DOS!  But didn't you say that the first byte is the string length?  So why not just use that instead of scanning, if the 13 is always at the end?  `mov`+`add` is better than a loop.

Comment: Because the 13 is included as part of the size (the first byte counts the 13).

Comment: So subtract 1.  Do you need to copy the filename out of the PSP at all?  Couldn't you just call the open-file system call with a pointer to the string in the PSP?  Write a terminating `0` over the `13` if needed.

Comment: Agree, @PeterCordes, replacing 13 by 0 would do it. I guess that´s another answer to the question (post it!).

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez The byte count from the DOS command line does __not__ include the terminating carriage return!

Comment: @Fifoernik, it does. When you type the name of your program and add the argument, you finish with ENTER key. This key code is stored too (I am watching it on my screen right now when reading the DTA).

Comment: How does the DTA relate to the command line? I know it's placed by default at the same place in memory but you should never mix these concepts. The DTA can and most probably will get placed elsewhere.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez The OP's question is only about the commandline. Dragging the DTA into your answer is most confusing! As user Fifoernik commented you should never mix these concepts. At program start they share the same memory but that's about it. Moreover since at program start the DS and ES registers point at the PSP there's really no reason to use any of the functions that you mention.

Comment: @SepRoland, the DS and ES are not always pointing to the program arguments, if you need to get the program arguments after changing DS or ES, you MUST know where arguments were (unless they're gone), that's why the DTA and the PSP are important, because the program arguments lie there. So, you and Fifoernik, click here = https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=XxP8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=int+21h+ah%3D2fh&source=bl&ots=130J9jR69I&sig=vu3vqrIpvtcvqxE-3KOwTwb2LZk&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=int%2021h%20ah%3D2fh&f=false . Updated answer with link. If you downvoted, change your downvote.